# Bootloop after flashing TWRP (Also lost recovery)

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, boot-loop, fastboot

So I was going to root this (previsouly healthy) BQ A4.5. Unlocked the bootloader and flashed [TWRP from here](https://twrp.me/bq/bqaquarisa45.html):

```
$ fastboot oem unlock
(bootloader) Start unlock flow

OKAY [ 32.954s]
Finished. Total time: 32.960s
$ fastboot flash recovery downloads/twrp-3.3.1-0-dendeone.img
target reported max download size of 134217728 bytes
Sending 'recovery' (11342 KB)...
OKAY [  0.378s]
Writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.335s]
Finished. Total time: 0.727s
$ fastboot reboot bootloader
rebooting into bootloader
OKAY [  0.003s]
Finished. Total time: 0.058s
$ fastboot reboot
Rebooting...

Finished. Total time: 0.058s
```

The first reboot to bootloader didn't do anything.
Now it's on a bootloop which states:

```
Orange State
Your device has been unlocked and can't be trusted
Your device will boot in 5 seconds
```

Pressing *Volume Up + PowerOn* used to work for recovery (that's how I got into fastboot mode).
Now, pressing *Volume Up/Down/Up+Down + PowerOn* doesn't do anything, fastboot stands indefinitely `< waiting for any device >`, and adb always responds with `error: no devices/emulators found` regardless of when it's run.
If I press *Volume Up+Down* it turns off. Plugging in USB it turns on. Nothing else seems to respond.

`dmesg` states:

```
[32774.364937] usb 2-7: new high-speed USB device number 59 using xhci_hcd
[32774.514434] cdc_acm 2-7:1.0: Zero length descriptor references
[32774.514450] cdc_acm: probe of 2-7:1.0 failed with error -22
[32774.554519] cdc_acm 2-7:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[32777.142205] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 59
```

The disconnect happens before the bq logo appears.

Trash bin time?

Comment: [Orange state](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/boot-flow#unlocked-devices) is just a warning shown by bootloader on unlocked devices which implement Android Verified Boot. All that you need to do is find the proper key combination to boot into bootloader mode, which is definitely running.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with my BQ M8. Here is how I solved it:

1. With the phone connected via USB, launch CMD to run ADB and test as many times as needed that the PC and terminal can talk to each other with the command `adb devices`. Eventually, after several attempts, it will return the device and number. Possibly stating the work "recovery".
2. Go into bootloader with the command `adb reboot bootloader`. As before, try it as many times as needed until it works (that means you will have to re-run the ADB, and un-plug, plug the phone).
3. Once on bootloader (you can verify because the phone screen is in "Fastboot..." state), you have to launch in your PC the FLASH TOOLS (hope you know how to use it)
4. In FlashTools, select only BOOT and RECOVERY tickmarks, and leave the rest unmarked. Then Press on the DOWNLOAD green arrow
5. Now back in ADB window, use the command `fastboot reboot`. This will restart the phone, and FlashTools will immediately kick in, flashing the BOOT and RECOVERY files back in your phone (it takes milliseconds)
6. The phone will restart and this time you will have it all in STOCK (you'll also have the bootloader locked again).